# Google Guice nested assisted injects

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a factory that looks like this:

```
public class Factory {

    public Client createClient(String url) {
        UrlBuilder urlBuilder = new UrlBuilder(url);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpProcessor processor = new CompressionHttpProcessor();
        httpClient.addRequestInterceptor(processor);
        httpClient.addResponseInterceptor(processor);

        return new Client(httpClient, urlBuilder);
    }
}
```

A class like this:

```
public class Facade {

    private Factory factory;
    private String url;

    public Facade(Factory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        Client client = factory.createClient(url);
        // do stuff with client
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

How do I properly use Google Guice to do the same? I tried assisted injections, but I'm not sure how I would create the "UrlBuilder". Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Setting class that holds the URL and did this:

```
public MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final Settings settings;
    public MyModule(Settings settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    // configure

    @Provides
    private UrlBuilder createUrlBuilder(Settings settings) {
        return new UrlBuilder(settings.getUrl());
    }
}
```

It kinda works, but I'm not sure I like it.

Answer (score 0):

> Guice alleviates the need for factories and the use of new in your
>   Java code.

Your `factory` code seems to violate that principle.

You may want to redesign *facade* so that it receives the `client` object via injection (using setClient) method.